# Not able to display value in an hidden field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

```
function show(a,b) {
    var origin = document.getElementById('Subadd').value;
    var destination = a.value;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [origin],
          destinations: [destination],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, calcD);
}

function calcD(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
          var results = response.rows[i].elements;
          for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
              c= results[j].distance.text;
              b.value=c;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Here a and b are two text field id. From text field 1 onchange the function show() will work and alerts value of c in CalcD() function. But I can't pass the value of c into the textfield with id b.

Comment: So your problem is this line `b.value=c;`? I don't see how you reference the `b` variable in that function

Answer (score 1):

It occurs because b is undefined in function `CalcD`. You must pass it to function or call it directly using some methods like `document.getElementById`.
Then your code must be something like this:

```
function show(a,b) {
    var origin = document.getElementById('Subadd').value;
    var destination = a.value;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
          origins: [origin],
          destinations: [destination],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, calcD);
}

function calcD(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
          var results = response.rows[i].elements;
          for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
              c= results[j].distance.text;
              b = document.getElementById('id of b input');
              b.value=c;
          }
        }
    }
}
```